# How to write the value over each bullet in small div permanently in chart js

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, jscharts

I have this data

```
chartLabels = ['2018', '2019', '2020', 'TTM',]
priceToSaleRatioData = [3.37, 5.73, 1.88, 4.6,]
```

I want this to display over each bullet in my line chart But it should be Permanently written in some box.

Here's my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/30pafj91/1/) with the code I got so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`chartjs-plugin-datalabels`](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/) plugin.

First you'll have to [register](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/getting-started.html#registration) the plugin, then you can define the desired options inside `options.plugins.datalabels`.

> If beside the value, you also want to display the corresponding label or some additional text, you need to define a [`formatter`](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/formatting.html) function.

Please take a look at the runnable code below and see how it works.

```js
const chartLabels = ['2018', '2019', '2020', 'TTM'];
const priceToSaleRatioData = [3.37, 5.73, 1.88, 4.6];

Chart.register(ChartDataLabels);
new Chart('chart', {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: chartLabels,
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My Dataset',
      data: priceToSaleRatioData,
    }]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        color: 'blue',
        anchor: 'end',
        align: 'top',
        formatter: (v, ctx) => {
          let label = ctx.chart.data.labels[ctx.dataIndex];
          if (label != 'TTM') {
            label = 'year ' + label;
          }
          return label + ': ' + v;
        }
      }
    },
    scales: {
      y: {
        max: 8
      },
      x: {
        offset: true
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
datalabels: {
  formatter: function(value, context) {
    return context.chart.data.labels[context.dataIndex];
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/2.0.0/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" height="100"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I am getting the data? is it possible to concatenate some text and label along with data?

Comment: @Adeel: Just updated my answer to also show how to customize `datalabels`

Comment: appreciate it. Can I style this part? I want to give font some size.

Comment: @Adeel: there exist many options to style the text (i.e. `font.size`): see https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/options.html#options

Comment: I have tried but those styles aren't working on this part over each bullet. I actually want to give a small border to the text above each bullet.  heres the link https://jsfiddle.net/1nfh5prg/

Comment: @Adeel: `backgroundColor` and `borderColor` may be the options you're looking for: see https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/samples/charts/line.html